# How To Use New Django Allauth MFA

Tags: django-allauth

I've got a project which utilises Django Allauth. I saw they recently released MFA within Django Allauth, but I have no idea how to implement it, and [the documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mfa/introduction.html) is fairly limited at the moment.

Can anyone explain what the steps are to implementing the Django Allauth MFA in a bit more detail?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple.

You need to `pip install django-allauth[mfa]`

You add it to settings.py apps as `allauth.mfa`

Also include this setting: `MFA_ADAPTER = "allauth.mfa.adapter.DefaultMFAAdapter"`

then run `python manage.py migrate`

if you go to `localhost/accounts/`, you would see a list of all the available url django-allauth offers.

At the bottom, you should see "accounts/2fa". If you navigate to `localhost/accounts/2fa`, then you would see that it is set up. You need to configure your **signups** to redirect to that page to take advantage of it.